# Apache: Add header to one specific url?

Tags: apache-2.2, content-negotiation

I just configured some Content negotiation for my root url based on this [Apache Document](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/content-negotiation.html)
and it seems to work great.

As my site also set a language cookie, I tested the following in my virtualhost (also mentionned in the doc)

```
  SetEnvIf Cookie "lang=([^;]+)" prefer-language=$1
  Header append Vary cookie
```

But then, As I only have one URL with negotiated content, I don't want to send a Vary: Cookie for all requests. It would prevent all caching to be efficient as a sessionid is also stored in a cookie (correct me if i'm wrong).

So my question is how can I only append the Vary header for this specific url.

I already tried to specified the directives in a Location Directory or Files section, but none seemed to work.

```
<Location "/">
  Header append Vary cookie
</Location>
```

> > The vary header is sent for / but also for /eng/index.html and all requests

```
<Directory /my/htdocs>
  Header append Vary cookie
</Directory>
```

> > The vary header is not sent neither for / nor for any requests

```
<Files "/index.html">
  Header append Vary cookie
</Files>
```

> > The vary header is not sent neither for / nor for any requests

Comment: Please include the things you tried which didn't work.

Comment: What results did you get from those attempts? Those seem like they would work, did you potentially have browser caching messing with your testing?

Comment: I must recheck but either the vary header was sent for all requests or for none.